Why I am getting the 499 error for the first time and again getting the 201 success response
@router.post("/webhook", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, include_in_schema=False)
async def create_webhook_record(request: dict):
    """ Create a Webhook Response """

    if not request:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Unauthorised Request Request is missing")

    event_type = request.get("event_type")
    if not event_type:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Unauthorised Request event type missing")

    order = request.get("order")
    if not order:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Unauthorised Request order is missing")

    transaction = request.get("transaction")
    if not transaction:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Unauthorised Request transaction is missing")

    order_id = request.get("order_id")
    transaction_id = request.get("transaction_id")
    request_status = request.get("status")
    request_message = request.get("message")

    invoice_id = order.get("invoice_id")
    total_amount = order.get("total_amount")

    transaction_status = transaction.get("status")

    request_model = WebhookIn(
        invoice_id=invoice_id,
        order_id=order_id,
        transaction_id=transaction_id,
        total_amount=total_amount,
        event_type=event_type,
        status=request_status,
        message=request_message,
        transaction_status=transaction_status
    )

    transaction_details = await api.get_transaction_by_invoice_id(
        invoice_id=request_model.invoice_id)
    if not transaction_details:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                            detail="transaction not found.")

    merchant_id = transaction_details.get("merchant_id")
    mcode = transaction_details.get("mcode")

    webhook_response = await api.create_webhook_record(
        request=request_model, merchant_id=merchant_id, mcode=mcode)
    if webhook_response:
        merchant = await crud.get_merchant_by_id(id=merchant_id)
        is_callback = merchant.get("is_callback")
        if is_callback:
            merchant = await crud.get_callback_url_by_merchant_id(
                merchant_id=merchant_id)
            callback_url = merchant.get("callback_url")
            await api.post_callback_url(callback_url=callback_url,
                                request_model=request_model)

        return {"message": "received"}
    return {"message": "received but could  not write"}

I am getting this :
6x.1.2xx.2xx - - [05/Aug/2024:11:49:43 +0530] "POST /payments/webhook HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Ktor client" 6x.1.2xx.2xx - - [05/Aug/2024:11:50:12 +0530] "POST /payments/webhook HTTP/1.1" 201 22 "-" "Ktor client"
I am getting this issue some times that's why callback response posting in the DB twice
can someone suggest
I am using fastapi, mysql-connector-python and hosted behind nginx.
how to figure this out anyone please...

499 is a client closed connection, have you tried it with other simple client like curl insteado of Ktor?

@TlmaK0 No, I haven't tried that yet, but this issue occurs only once or twice out of 1000 requests approx. . I'm looking for solutions to prevent this from happening.

Is it an stress test? It sounds like a retry from the client when connection fails

@TlmaK0 yes client is retrying while getting 499 response code that's the issue which breaking my code... Not a stress testing its a live application I am getting this issue one or two per day

Look at the service logs, there should be something indicating that the server takes too long to respond to some requests (too much traffic or locking), then the client (or proxy) closes the connection before finishing and tries again.
